# Timeout prompt won't stop showing

Tags: batch-file

I'm attempting to use Batch for the first time, and I'm running into some trouble with the timeout command. I'm making a simple backup program to backup certain files to my flash drive, and this is the beginning.I'm trying to make it so that the prompt does not show how much of the countdown is left. This is what I have:

```
ECHO Deleting current backup location...
RD /s /q F:\CurrentBackup

@TIMEOUT /t 10

ECHO Setting up new backup...
MKDIR F:\CurrentBackup
MKDIR F:\CurrentBackup\Documents
MKDIR F:\CurrentBackup\Pictures
MKDIR F:\CurrentBackup\Desktop
MKDIR F:\CurrentBackup\Music

rem xcopy C:\Eric D:\
```

Can anyone help me with this seemingly simple problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can tell a command, where to write it's output. If you don't, it writes it to screen

```
TIMEOUT /t 10 >nul
```

will write the output to a "Null-Device" (also known as "Nirwana")

by the way: `@` does not suppress the output of a command, but suppress the repetition of the commandline. It's a kind of "one-line-`echo off`"

Normally, you put

```
@echo off
```

as the first line of a script.
`echo off` will turn command repetition off, and the `@` does the same thing for this very line (as the `echo off` is not yet active for this line)

Comment: Alright, that doesn't show the countdown, but now it just shows "TIMEOUT /t 10 1>nul" on that line. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: read the second part of my anser, and then put `@echo off` as the first line of your script.